# Print footer first page only and image fill second page

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a report and i need the footer to be printed in first page only and print the second page with a image filling all the page.

I am using HTML-Sheets-of-Paper to display the report, tried changing the position, bottom of the .divFooter but it don't display the report the way i want.

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
    .divFooter {
        align:center;
      text-align:center;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
</style>

<p class="divFooter">
            <img src="img/assinatura2.png" style="margin;margin: 0 auto;display: block;">
            footerInfo...
            </p>

        </div>
        <div id="page2" class="page">
        <img class="imgfull" src="img/contracapa.jpg" />
        </div>
```

The current behavior is that the footer is being printed on all the pages and the image is displaying small (not filling all the second page).
Thanks

Comment: your `class="imgfull"` is not defined for any behaviour, so it will show on all pages. for small image, set image to cover `id="page2"` .

Comment: the imgfull is the image to cover all the second page. I tried adding the css to background-size:cover, shows ok on browser, on print shows only the first page

Comment: Solved the image using these styles: .imgfull{
 width: 100%;
}
#page2 {
 padding: 0px !important;
}

Comment: The problem with the image is that on print, it sets the margin on image, not filling it the whole page. And about the footer, it repeats on all pages